# How to use {hjkl} to repeatedly move cursor in ideavim

Tags: pycharm, ideavim

I am using the ideavim plugin for PyCharm (mac), but it seems that I cannot move the cursor continuously with {hjkl}. When I press down the keys, it can only make one move and then stuck. But what I expect is it moves repeatedly like using arrow keys. What should I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a similar problem related to sublime. Here is the answer to that question:
https://gist.github.com/kconragan/2510186

Therefore, what I should do in my case is just to type in terminal:

```
defaults write com.jetbrains.pycharm ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

Restart PyCharm and that's it!

Answer (score 10):

great answer @Codinfox.
In my case I was having the same problem with Rider for mac and in order to fix it I just run almost the same command in the terminal. Then restart the app.

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

again, thanks :)

Comment: This works, although I notice that the movements are a lot slower compared to ideavim on windows or Linux. :(

Comment: THANK YOU! You just made my life mush easier. :)